# JAVA - Somar dígitos de um número X em um intervalo de A e B

Tags: java, algoritmo

Preciso calcular a soma dos dígitos de um X número em um intervalo de A e B;

Por exemplo, se X = 3, A = 10 e B = 30, então a reposta é 3, pois existem três números
no intervalo de [10, 30] cuja soma dos dígitos é igual a três: 12, 21 e 30.

Restrições: (1 ≤ X ≤ 36), (1 ≤ A ≤ 10 000), (1 ≤ B ≤ 10 000)e (A ≤ B)

Seu programa deve produzir uma única linha, contendo um único inteiro, quantos
números no intervalo dado têm a soma de dígitos indicada.

O código que elaborei foi este ↓

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
    int x, a, b;

    System.out.format("Informe o valor de 'X' de 1 até 36: ");
    x = in.nextInt();

    if (x >= 1 && x <= 36) {
        System.out.format("Informe o valor de 'A' de 1 até 10000: ");
        a = in.nextInt();
        
        if (a >= 1 && a <= 10000) {
            System.out.format("Informe o valor de 'B' de 1 até 10000: ");
            b = in.nextInt();

            if (b >= 1 && b <= 10000) {  
                
                int soma = 0;
                for (int i = a; i <= b; i++){
                         
                    soma = i % 10; // imprime o resto de 10, 11, 12... 
                   
                     
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Encontrei o resto dos números no intervalo de 10 a 30, porém eu não consigo achar o quociente desses números para somar eles.

```
    soma = i % 10;
    i = soma / 10;
```

E não obtive o quociente dos números para depois somar e verificar qual é igual a X.

Não consigo entender aonde estou errando para achar uma solução.

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi bem o que tu fez com relação a soma, mas pelo o que eu entendi, tu poderia fazer desse modo:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class teste {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
    int x;
    int intervalStart; // numero que indica começo do intervalo
    int intervalEnd; // numero que indica final do intervalo


    System.out.print("Informe o valor de 'X' de 1 até 36: ");
    x = in.nextInt();

    if (x >= 1 && x <= 36) {
        System.out.print("Informe o 1º de valor de intervalo de 1 até 10000: ");
        intervalStart = in.nextInt();
        
        if (intervalStart >= 1 && intervalStart <= 10000) {
            System.out.print("Informe o 2º valor de intervalo de 1 até 10000: ");
            intervalEnd = in.nextInt();

            if (intervalEnd >= 1 && intervalEnd <= 10000) {  
                
                for (int currentNumber = intervalStart; currentNumber <= intervalEnd; currentNumber++) { // percorre toda a lista do intervalo
                    int aux = currentNumber; // criando um auxiliar
                    int digitSum = 0; // soma dos dígitos
                    while(aux > 0){
                        digitSum += aux % 10; // somando digitos
                        aux /= 10; // pegando o proximo digito
                    }
                    if(digitSum == x) // verifica se a soma é igual ao que foi escolhido no começo
                        selectedNumberAmount++; // se for, ela soma na quantidade de números filtrados
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(selectedNumberAmount); // mostra a quantidade
    in.close(); // fechando o scanner
}
```

}